# App freezes when calling AVAssetExportSession.cancelExport() using customVideoCompositorClass

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'm exporting video using `AVMutableVideoComposition` and `customVideoCompositorClass` which works fine. But by cancelling the `AVAssetExportSession` via `cancelExport()` my app goes hanging and not responding at all.

```swift
func cancel() {
  exportSession?.cancelExport()
  exportSession = nil
}
```

I tried to bypass the `customVideoCompositorClass` for testing purposes and was able to cancel the export as intended. No hangs, everything smooth. However I can't bypass the custom compositor since it handles all the drawing logic.

Here is the configuration of `AVMutableVideoComposition`:

```swift
let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
mainComposition.customVideoCompositorClass = CustomVideoCompositor.self
mainComposition.frameDuration = // time range
mainComposition.renderSize = // render size
mainComposition.instructions = [ ... ]
```

and this is the inner part of custom video compositor which I borrowed from `AVCustomEdit` repository in [GitHub](https://github.com/glennneiger/AVCustomEdit/blob/master/AVCustomEdit-Swift/APLCustomVideoCompositor.swift):

```swift
  ...

  private var renderingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.identifier.CustomVideoCompositor.RenderingQueue")
  private var shouldCancelAllRequests = false

  func startRequest(_ request: AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest) {
    autoreleasepool {
      renderingQueue.async {
        if self.shouldCancelAllRequests {
          request.finishCancelledRequest()
          return
        }

        guard let frame = self.newRenderedPixelBuffer(forRequest: request) else {
          request.finish(with: errorForInvalidPixelBuffer)
          return
        }

        request.finish(withComposedVideoFrame: frame)
      }
    }
  }

  func cancelAllPendingVideoCompositionRequests() {
    // Pending requests will call `finishCancelledRequest`, those already rendering
    // will call `finishWithComposedVideoFrame`.
    renderingQueue.sync {
      shouldCancelAllRequests = true
    }

    // Start accepting requests again.
    renderingQueue.async { [self] in
      shouldCancelAllRequests = false
    }
  }
 
  ...
```

As far as understand my custom compositor should be triggered with `cancelAllPendingVideoCompositionRequests()` method when calling `AVAssetExportSession.cancelExport()` which should cancel all the upcoming frames and end up with `request.finishCancelledRequest()`. But in practice I couldn't even hit the debug breakpoint on this line.

Any thoughts on this very strange behaviour?